# Importing python file in AWS Cloud9 Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud9

I built a simple lambda function using AWS Cloud9.  Now I want my lambda to do a bit more.  So I created another python file with some functions and saved it in the same directory.

```
myLambdaName
  - myLambdaName
     - lambda_function.py
     - other_function.py
```

In my lambda function, I try to import this ( `import other_function`).

If I run the function in the cloud9 terminal, no issues (`python3 lambda_function.py`).  But when I go to test the lambda function locally, via AWS Resources tab > Run (local), I get the error that my new python file doesn't exist:

> Unable to import module 'myLambdaName/lambda_function': No module named 'other_function'

What am I missing here?  How do I tell the lambda to pick up the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your function name to the import path, like

```
import myLambdaName.other_function
```

See screenshot below for example that I've just tested with `ApplicationName` being the application name, while `FunctionName` being the function name.

[image]